Routing VPN Traffic to a Linux Container on macOS Host for HTTP Access
I have Linux container running on a macOS host. On the host I have a VPN client running.
I am able to access machines on the VPN network from my Linux container. What I cannot do is to route the traffic that is coming to the VPN client to the Linux container.
What I would like to do, getting HTTP Post requests from a client on the VPN network via the host's VPN client to a web server running on the Linux container.
I tried to add a route, like this:
ip route add 10.10.14.32 via 172.17.0.1

With 10.10.14.32 being the IP of the VPN client on the mac and 172.17.0.1 the gateway of the Linux container network. That did not work.
I did some further research with ChatGPT. The reason why it is not routing the traffic to my Linux container, because it does not apply my custom rule in /etc/pf.conf.
This is the line, that I added:
rdr pass on utun9 proto tcp from any to 10.10.15.164 port 8001 -> 172.17.0.2 port 8001
Reloading PF with sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf and verifying with sudo pfctl -sr the custom rule does not show up.
Then I tried to create a custom anchor file containing the custom rule. Adding this line: load anchor "custom" from "/etc/pf.anchors/custom"to /etc/pf.conf, again reloading the config file. Verifying it and the custom rule does not show up.
This is shown, when executing sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf: pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup. See /etc/pf.conf for further details.
And this is shown, when executing sudo pfctl -sr:
No ALTQ support in kernel ALTQ related functions disabled scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble anchor "com.apple/*" all

I would just expose the port from the docker contain onto the host -p switch, when starting the docker container. As far as I know, when you do that the VPN won't see it any different than a service running on the host itself (that binds a port).
If you are concerned about exposing the docker service on the LAN you can probably pass the IP address of the VPN interface to -p switch to limit which IP gets bound.

Thank you for your answer. I exposed the port on which my web server is running on in the container. But it still does not get the requests from a client in the VPN network. When I test with nc -zv localhost 8001 the web server gets the request, but when I run nc -zv 10.10.15.164 8001 the IP of the VPN client on my macOS host, the web server does not receive anything.
